# Download a VF page as pdf with a button

Tags: visualforce, pdf, pagereference

I want to have a button that dowload a pdf page as a file related to the record from where I pressed the button. My page is working well, but I had to add a controller so clicking on the button download the page instead of showing me the page. I know that A way to do it is to creating a second VF page that will call the "real" page I want. But I prefered to find a way where I only needed to add a parameter to the page for the problem where the getContent() method call a new page that calls a new page and so on.

here is the code of my controller I greatly inspired myself from [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/328288/too-many-nested-getcontent-calls-error-on-button-click-to-create-and-attach-pdf) for my code

```
public class certificateDownloader {
    public ApexPages.StandardController stdController {get; set;}

    public certificateDownloader(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        stdController = controller; 
    }

    public pageReference downloadPdf2() {
        if (!Test.isRunningTest()) {//when accessing by a record
            if (ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('doNotSavePDF') == null) {
                ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('doNotSavePDF', 'true');
                Blob certificatePdf = ApexPages.currentPage().getContent();
                Attachment file = new Attachment(parentId = stdController.getId(), Name='test.pdf', body=certificatePdf);
                insert file;
            }
        
            PageReference page = stdController.view();
            page.setRedirect(true);
            return page;
        }
        else {return null;}
    }
}
```

here is the VF page:

```
<apex:page standardController="WorkOrder" renderAs="pdf" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" extensions="certificateDownloader" action="{!downloadPdf2}">
stuff
</apex:page>
```

but for some reason the pdf downloaded as an Attachment is not working and seems corrupted each time I try opening it. I don't think the problem is with my VFpage, since it works well when I emove the `action` parameter from the `<apex:page>`

**EDIT :** using getContentAsPdf() method isn't working either, the pdf it gives me is blank, and it doesn't change if I change the `renderAs` parameter in `<apex:page>`.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using [`getContentAsPDF()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_System_PageReference_getContentAsPDF.htm)?

Comment: because It doesn't work either. instead of having a corrupted file I just have a blank pdf

Comment: I see, please [edit] your post to include that important detail, since `getConentAsPDF()` is the expected way to this.

Comment: Are you trying to download the pdf or save it to Salesforce? You can probably do both, but please be specific. I'll put an answer for inserting the Attachment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to render the page as PDF in Apex, not just on the page:

```
if (ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('doNotSavePDF') == null) {
  
  PageReference myPage = Page.CURRENT_PAGE_NAME;
  myPage.getParameters().put('doNotSavePDF', 'true');
  Id woId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
  myPage.getParameters().put('Id', woId);
  Blob certificatePdf = myPage.getContent();
  Attachment file = new Attachment(parentId = stdController.getId(), Name='test.pdf', body=certificatePdf);
  insert file;
}
```

This will save the PDF as an attachment.

Don't return anything from the method. Just return null. It should insert the attachment AND show the page as a PDF to the user.

Comment: WOW it really worked. I don't understand how should I have known to take Page.CURRENT_PAGE_NAME instead of ApexPages.currentPage(), but thank you so much